# How does the Radix-2 Montgomery multiplication algorithm R2MM work on bit level?

Tags: algorithm, binary, primes, multiplication

The following algorithm is for modular multiplication modulo a prime number p, xi represents the bit number "i" of the X input, Y is the second input.

i know how to implement this algorithm but i would like to understand it's functioning on bit level, like why do we check for even or odd and why do we add xi*Y or xi*Y +p and divide by 2 (bit-shift) consequently to the condition?

```
  1: procedure R2MM(X, Y, p)
  2: S ← 0
  3: for i ← 0 to n − 1 do
  4: if (S + xiY ) is even then
  5: S ← (S + xiY )/2
  6: else
  7: S ← (S + xiY + p)/2
  8: end if
  9: end for
  10: if S ≥ p then
  11: S ← S − p
  12: end if
  13: end procedure
```

i did not find any source that explains this algorithm on bit level, only blind implementations of it.

Edit 1: this [Paper1](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777282-X/S0025-5718-1985-0777282-X.pdf) seem to clarify my issue of understanding the algorithm, it enlightened me on some aspects but the mathematical nature of the explanation made it a bit complex to fully comprehend, i got that S is a sort of accumulator and that we add N on the odd case of Si to make it even so the dividing it by 2 makes it an integer, but i still don't get why we divide by 2, the answer is probably that induction proof but i don't see fully how, any explanation would be of great help.

Comment: The [original paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777282-X/S0025-5718-1985-0777282-X.pdf) explains it well, particularly section 3 for the bit-oriented version.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you, that section helped me understand most of the process, however, i would need some clarifications on the induction part and how i sit that we need to divide by  2, i know that the two are related but i want to understand this algorithm on a deep level, i will now edit my question by adding your source